# AWS Direct Connect - Physical Connection/Ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-direct-connect

Is it possible to just connect a *single* 1Gb connection to have a workable AWS Direct Connect service?

We have a single 1Gb connection already physically installed from our DC to AWS

Our Service Provider is now asking for the LOA to complete the service.

To generate the LOA you need to create the Direct Connection in the AWS console.

We only have a single 1Gb connection to this one AWS location.

I understand AWS would likely still charge for the unused port. (30c per hour)

I accept in this scenario there is no device/link/location redundancy.

The question is: Do we need to physically patch/connect to BOTH AWS ports in order to have a workable Direct Connect service?

Its not clear from the AWS documentation if this would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it help you but I fount this article form 2019 https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-gigabit-connectivity-options-for-amazon-direct-connect/